fastapi service throwing exception 'no running event loop'
I have a fastapi service that is using a library. The library is doing I/O.
I converted the library to be full async. Changed the unit tests, and all the tests pass.
Now when I try to use that library in my fastapi service using async await I am getting the error:
  File \"/Users/ferozed/stash/services/validation-api/validation_api/main.py\", line 5, in <module>
    from .routers import root
  File \"/Users/ferozed/stash/services/validation-api/validation_api/routers/root.py\", line 4, in <module>
    from ..api import *
  File \"/Users/ferozed/stash/services/validation-api/validation_api/api.py\", line 5, in <module>
    from .singletons import SINGLETONS
  File \"/Users/ferozed/stash/services/validation-api/validation_api/singletons.py\", line 31, in <module>
    SINGLETONS = Singleton()
  File \"/Users/ferozed/stash/services/validation-api/validation_api/singletons.py\", line 8, in __init__
    self._event_registry_cache = event_registry_cache()
  File \"/Users/ferozed/stash/services/validation-api/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/event_validator/event_registry/event_registry_cache.py\", line 20, in __init__
    self._client = event_registry_client()
  File \"/Users/ferozed/stash/services/validation-api/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/event_validator/event_registry/event_registry_client.py\", line 27, in __init__
    self._session = aiohttp.ClientSession()
  File \"/Users/ferozed/stash/services/validation-api/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py\", line 294, in __init__
    loop = loop or asyncio.get_running_loop()

I am initializing the objects in a singleton as follows:
class Singleton(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self._event_registry_cache = event_registry_cache()

The event_registry_cache() initializes an event_registry_client in it's constructor. The constructor then tries to create an aiohttp.ClientSession(). This is the part that is throwing the exception
Here is a simplified repro:
import asyncio
import aiohttp

class client(object):

  def __init__(self):
    self._session = aiohttp.ClientSession()

  async def do(self):
    with self._session.get('http://www.google.com') as resp:
      await resp.text

class singleton(object):

  def __init__(self):
    self._client = client()

  async def do(self):
    await self._client.do()

SINGLETON = singleton()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  loop = asyncio.get_running_loop() or asyncio.new_event_loop()
  loop.run_until_complete(SINGLETON.do())


This returns the same error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ferozed/stash/services/clickstream-event-validation-api/clickstream_event_validation_api/repro.py", line 21, in <module>
    SINGLETON = singleton()
  File "/Users/ferozed/stash/services/clickstream-event-validation-api/clickstream_event_validation_api/repro.py", line 16, in __init__
    self._client = client()
  File "/Users/ferozed/stash/services/clickstream-event-validation-api/clickstream_event_validation_api/repro.py", line 7, in __init__
    self._session = aiohttp.ClientSession()
  File "/Users/ferozed/stash/services/clickstream-event-validation-api/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 294, in __init__
    loop = loop or asyncio.get_running_loop()
RuntimeError: no running event loop

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?
One guess is that I can make the session initialization lazy so that it is always initialized inside of a loop.
But is there any way to get this working without lazy init?

This question would be easier to answer with a [mcve] that we can run locally to reproduce the behavior you're asking about.

At a blind guess, you're trying to instantiate it outside of any async code (maybe as a global variable?).

Yeah, that is right. It is part of the initialization of the singleton.

You might find this answer and this answer helpful.

You're initializing an async object aiohttp.ClientSession() from the init method which is not async. Therefore, aiohttp.ClientSession() needs to be created within an active event loop.
You can benefit from the lazy initialization inside the startup event.
Here is my example code:
import aiohttp
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

class client(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._session = None

    async def initialize(self):
        self._session = aiohttp.ClientSession()

    async def do(self):
        async with self._session.get('http://www.google.com') as resp:
            return await resp.text()

class singleton(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._client = client()

    async def initialize(self):
        await self._client.initialize()

    async def do(self):
        return await self._client.do()

SINGLETON = singleton()

@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup_event():
    await SINGLETON.initialize()

@app.get("/")
async def read_root():
    return await SINGLETON.do()


Thanks! This seems like a possibility.
I could also just do a lazy init when I actually want to send a request. Then I dont need to add another function initialize.
